# NSObject: on the heap or the stack?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

Is an Objective-C object, e.g., `NSString`, placed on the stack or the heap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pointee of an Objective-C object is stored on the heap. But there are two exceptions: constant strings like `@"foo"` and [block literals](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) are stored in the `__DATA` segment (for global variables).

Normally none of ObjC objects will be stored on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

They are allocated on the heap. That's true for basically all Objective-C objects, blocks being the only exception I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm, aren't all objective-c objects dynamically allocated on the heap?

`NSString` has one exception to this rule - declaring them like `@"This is a string"`, they are not placed on the heap.